# <li> tags are not displayed when setting the style.display = none

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a `toggle` button that can set the tags with class `adsetTarget` of HTML tags "li" to be `hidden` or `visible` on click event.

During page load, the state of "li"  tags are hidden. This is the code that is setting the initial page load event to be `hidden`. This is working correctly.

```
var appBanners = document.getElementsByClassName('adsetTarget'), i;

    for (var i = 0; i < appBanners.length; i ++) {
        appBanners[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
```

Below is the code that is trying to set `toggle` button functionality. On clicking first time, it is displaying the content, but on clicking it again, the content is not hiding, can someone help.

```
var adsetTargets = document.getElementsByClassName('adsetTarget'), i;
    for (var i = 0; i < adsetTargets.length; i ++) {
        if (adsetTargets[i].style.display = 'none')
        adsetTargets[i].style.display = '';
        else
        adsetTargets[i].style.display = 'none'; //this is not working, I believe

        }
```

Comment: Where did you use jquery?

Comment: there's a typo in your `if` statements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the following line:

```
if (adsetTargets[i].style.display == 'none')
```

Notice the double equals?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to make it senstive to any styling you apply to your elements.
It will remember the elements previous style and re-apply it(in theory heh)

```js
function showhide() {
    var adsetTargets = document.getElementsByClassName('adsetTarget'), i;

    for (var i = 0; i < adsetTargets.length; i ++) {

        if (adsetTargets[i].style.display == 'none') {
            adsetTargets[i].style.display = adsetTargets[i].getAttribute('data-previous');
        }
        else {
            adsetTargets[i].setAttribute('data-previous',adsetTargets[i].style.display);
            adsetTargets[i].style.display = 'none'; //this is not working, I believe
        }

     }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="adsetTarget" style="display:table">abc</li>
  <li class="adsetTarget"  style="display:block">123</li>
  <li class="adsetTarget"  style="display:inline-block">def</li>
  <li class="adsetTarget"  style="display:inline-block">456</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" onclick="showhide()" value="click me">
```